# Stop auto-close of command prompt, that were started in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I have a PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -WorkingDirectory [Directory] -ArgumentList 'build'
Write-Output "starting: Main application "
```

That script is in a foreach which iterates directories. It opens a command prompt window and runs in each directory. After it's finished it closes the command prompt.

**I would like that the command-prompt window remains open after execution.**

Many similar questions answers with 'use pause' or 'use /k'

But how do I add this to my script?

I've tried:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -WorkingDirectory [Directory] -ArgumentList 'build /k'
Write-Output "starting: Main application " 

Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -WorkingDirectory [Directory] -ArgumentList 'build & pause'
Write-Output "starting: Main application "
```

And many other variation. I don't know how to pass the command

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd' -WorkingDirectory [Directory] -ArgumentList '/k dotnet build'`

Comment: start.exe has a wait parameter, like this: `start /wait dotnet build`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PetSerAl it's:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd' -WorkingDirectory [Directory] -ArgumentList '/k dotnet build'
```